# Recovering data from Samsung SM-A405FN/DS with black screen

Tags: data-recovery

I have a Samsung Galaxy A40 (SM-A405FN/DS) with a smashed, black screen.  I'd like to recover data from the phone (as much as possible).

I know the OS on the phone is still running, because the phone connects to WiFi (it shows up as an active device in the list of connected device on my router web interface, and I can even ping it) and I can plug in a USB-C to USB-A adapter and connect a keyboard to it. The keyboard seems to work because the Num Lock LED toggles when I press the Num key. I presume a mouse would work, too, but because I don't have a screen, I can't see where the mouse is. I do have a Samsung USB-C to HDMI adapter (EE-P3200), but it doesn't do anything, presumably because it requires USB 3.0 to work, but the Galaxy A40 only has USB 2.0 support.

I read all sorts of manuals on the internet on data recovery, but they all involve turning on USB debugging in order to be able to access the phone. I can't do that, with the screen broken.

Does anyone have any suggestions where to go from here? Is there any way I can make use of the USB keyboard?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the touchpad still working? If it is i just found a video to enabling usb debugging on your phone but you will have to scramble in the dark to do this.

Comment: I don't know if the touch pad is still working - I have no way to tell, because the screen is kaputt. I also found a video about how to enable USB debugging with the touch pad working (probably same video). But I also can't access the screenshots on the phone - without unlocking it, there is no way to access the files from a computer...

Comment: get a second device, do everything "blind" in parallel on both devices

Comment: try to increase the volume and scramble for the slider and if you hear is beeping aftr sliding maybe it works(or try another test)